# Custom section and subsection make problems in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec, amsart

I got some problems while using `amsart` class and `titlesec` package.

I customized my section and subsection. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\scshape\center\large}{Lorem \thesection.}{0.5ex}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\bfseries}{Ipsum \thesubsection.}{0.5ex}{}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section{Lorem Ipsum}
Lorem Ipsum
\subsection{Dolor Sit Amet}
Dolor Sit Amet
\end{document}
```

The result is as below:
[image]

I have three problems. First, the section number is overlapped with section name. Second, I want to make section and subsection in TOC like `Lorem 1. Lorem Ipsum` and `Ipsum 1.1. Dolor Sit Amet`, but it shows just `1. Lorem Ipsum` and `1.1. Dolor Sit Amet`. The third one is that the space between subsection number and its name is too wide.

Is there any easy solution to solve this problem? I need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that amsart uses `\@tocline` to format the table of contents, which has 7 undocumented arguments (not the same arguments as `\@dottedtocline`).  The easiest solution is to copy the definitions for `\l@section` and `\l@subsection` from article class.

One alternative is to copy and modify the definitions of `\section` and `\subsection` from amsart.  Unfortunately, they call `\@startsection` which has 6 undocumented arguments.  OTOH, one might figure out what they do by trial and error.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\@dotsep{4.5}
\renewcommand*\l@section[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty
    \addvspace{1.0em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil
      \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2%
                                 \kern-\p@\kern\p@}\par
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\section}[display]{\scshape\center\large}{Lorem \thesection.}{0.5ex}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\bfseries}{Ipsum \thesubsection.}{0.5ex}{}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section{Lorem Ipsum}
Lorem Ipsum
\subsection{Dolor Sit Amet}
Dolor Sit Amet
\end{document}
```

Comment: By the solution the first problem is solved. However `\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{1.5em}{2.3em}}` does not work. It seems that `\@dottedtocline` is undefined.
Well, your answer is very useful for me. I will find the solution to solve the second problem Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually, it was `\@dotsep` that was undefined.  My bad.